# rails 3 + devise: how do I make the email confirmation links use secure https (not http)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, https, devise

How to I tell Devise to use https (not http) for all the account confirmation and password reminder etc links?

[note: I'm not looking for a solution to redirect *all* http to https, I just need devise to ensure the links it creates use https]

Our rails 3 app uses devise, and the app runs fine under https, however, devise always uses http for the email confirmation and password links it emails to users.

In our environment files I tried changing:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => "app1.mydomain.com" }
```

to

```
 { :host => "https://app1.mydomain.com" }
```

but predictably devise creates links that look like
http://https//app1.mydomain.com.... (eg, it prepends the :host settings with http:)

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`default_url_options` accepts the same hash parameters as [`url_for`](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/UrlHelper.html#method-i-url_for). So you should be able to do this:

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :protocol => 'https', :host => 'app1.mydomain.com' }
```

Comment: If you want for just specific links you can write in your mail template `link_to "show", root_url(:protocol=>'https')`, note that it should be `whatever_url` and not `whatever_path`

Comment: Very helpful. This appears to be a general problem with ActionMailer, not limited to Devise. Set ActionMailer::Base.default_url_options to {:protocol => 'https'} even if you are using force_ssl globally in your application.

Answer (score 3):

To set the protocol but also a subdirectory :

```
config.action_mailer.default_url_options = {
        :host => "www.example.com",
        :protocol => 'https',
        :only_path => false,
        :script_name => "/app" #add this attribute if your app is deployed in a subdirectory
    }
```

[Source](http://www.stormconsultancy.co.uk/blog/development/code-snippets/actionmailer-link-for-a-rails-app-deployed-in-a-sub-directory/)

Comment: www doesn't get included in the url