# Rails - Reset Password Link not working (Devise)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise

In the reset password mail i get link as

`http//example.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token` instead of

```
http://example.com/users/password/edit?reset_password_token.
```

**reset_password_instructions.html.erb**

```
<p>Hello <%= @resource.email %>!</p>

<p>Someone has requested a link to change your password, and you can do this through the link below.</p>

<p><%= link_to 'Change my password', edit_password_url(@resource, :reset_password_token => @resource.reset_password_token) %></p>

<p>If you didn't request this, please ignore this email.</p>
<p>Your password won't change until you access the link above and create a new one.</p>
```

Comment: what does this hold `config.action_mailer.default_url_options` in production.rb

Comment: @NitinJ config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :protocol => 'http', :host => 'example.com' }

Comment: try it by removing protocol part

Comment: @NitinJ  tried but its of no use

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5878329/rails-3-devise-how-do-i-make-the-email-confirmation-links-use-secure-https-n may be this help

Comment: @NitinJ tried it long back still the issue exists

Answer (score 0):

In devise.rb you have to change

```
config.mailer_sender = 'your_mail@gmail.com'
```

and add the following in the development.rb

```
  config.action_mailer.smtp_settings = {
 :address              => "smtp.gmail.com",
 :port                 => 587,
 :domain               => 'domain.com',
 :user_name            => '*********@gmail.com',
 :password             => '***********',
 :authentication       => :plain,
 :enable_starttls_auto => true  }
```

***allow less secure apps in gmail
restart the server***